# Can't use debugger in Samsung tizen TV 2016

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have the latest version of Tizen studio installed in my machine. We have an angular web application that works perfectly fine on all TV models except 2016 model. While trying to debug the app in 2016 TV i am not able to see any API calls or console output in the chrome debugger that is opening up when we press  Debug as> Tizen web application in the Tizen studio.

I had tried all the steps mentioned in the documentation:

https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/web-inspector/

The debugger should display all API Calls and inspect-ablT java-script console.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript support differs depending on TV year.

(See https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/specifications/web-engine-specifications).

It is very probable that you are using feature that won't work on 2016 devices and error occurs before the devtools starts.
Try to reload app after dev tools start to check it (CTRL + F5) and see if you have anything in the console.